# Страница с картой скроллится к карте

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Я добавил на страницу Тильды карту с помощью Api Яндекс.Карты

Таким образом, на странице https://apartpage.tilda.ws/page28028736.html установлена карта с возможностью построить маршрут.

Экспериментальным путем было обнаружено, что при перезагрузке из-за карты страница скроллится до нее.

Проблема именно на стороне кода карты.

Я понимаю, что в коде нет ничего, что отвечает за скролл, однако, если его убрать со страницы, она перезагружается нормально.

Вопрос:

Как сделать, чтобы страница с картой при перезагрузке не пролистывалась до карты, а перезагружалась как это принято - без смещения к карте?
[image: код ошибки]

Answer (score 1):

попробуй в начале `body` поставить невидимый элемент, тот же пустой `div` и таргетни его, с картами вечные проблемы

> все я понял че не так, у тебя при загрузке карты `input` просит ввести адрес, и так как до этого нету `tab` элементов, то он как первый получает фокус а следовательно страница скролится к нему

решается просто, создай невидимый элемент например кнопку, на которую будет падать `tab` либо найди другой способ, однако причина скрола указана выше